# Why is my form validation not working (onsubmit not triggering)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am writing a simple registration screen that allows a user to input their email address and password. As standard, I have the user inputting their email address and password twice to confirm. However, the `onsubmit` attribute on my form does not seem to be executing.

Here is the code:

**Fields**

```
 <form name="form" id="form" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm()" class="form col-md-12 center-block" method="POST">
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Full Name">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" name="cemail" id="cemail" placeholder="Confirm Email Address">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" form="form" type="submit" name="register" id="register">Register</button>
          <span class="pull-right"><a href="login.php">Login</a></span><br>
     </div>
 </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    function validateForm() {
      if (isSame(document.getElementById("email"), document.getElementById("cemail"))
       && isSame(document.getElementById("password"), document.getElementById("cpassword"))) {
        return true;
    } else {
      alert("Confirmation fields do not match, please retype and try again.");
      return false;
    }

    function isSame(elementA, elementB) {
      if (elementA.value.trim() == elementB.value.trim()) return true;
      else return false;
    }

    //ignore this 
    function submitForm() {
      document.getElementById("form").submit();
    }
</script>
```

I have tried to debug as much as possible, but it doesn't seem like my submit button is triggering the form's `onsubmit`. I have viewed the request log, and it is posting the data just fine, however.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try removing that `return` from the `onsubmit` attribute.

Comment: not about your answer, but you don't actually need the `else` in your isSame function since return false would just be a default behavior

Comment: @Rooster Did not know that, thanks! I'll keep that one in the memory banks.

Comment: @Rooster Or even better, you could use just `return elementA.value.trim() == elementB.value.trim()`.

Comment: @soktinpk ya good call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation of your code is incorrect: you are missing a `}` at the end of your `validateForm` function

Comment: ..... wow. You are right. I'm going to test but I feel like you have a checkmark coming your way.

Answer (score 0):

There's a syntax error; there's no closing bracket for the first function.

Also, your isSame function doesn't need an if statement.

Hopefully this helps:

JS:

```
function validateForm() {
    if(isSame(document.getElementById("email"), document.getElementById("cemail"))
      && isSame(document.getElementById("password"), document.getElementById("cpassword"))) {
        return true;
    }else{
        alert("Confirmation fields do not match, please retype and try again.");
        return false;
    }
}

function isSame(elementA, elementB) {
  return elementA.value.trim() == elementB.value.trim();
}
```

Comment: Oh crap, I'm fifteen minutes late. My bad.